# Installation is getting failed

Tags: storage

I used whatsapp for past 2 months and it gets uninstall by mistakenly and I tried to install it again but i can't install again it shows that I don't have sufficient storage what should I do please help me I need whatsapp for my study purposes

Comment: Please check the [insufficient-memory-tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some first-aid help

Answer (score 1):

Check your phone whether having enough space for the app. Normally it requires more space than the size of the app during installation.

If your phone has enough space, try to clear both cache and data for your Google Play in App Manager and perform a restart for your phone after clearing cache and data. It should work afterwards.

[Credit to this post. I tried this method and it worked for me](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-mini/435361-apps-won-t-install.html#post3884883)

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your phone memory is full you have to cleanup the internal memory of your phone.
Go to settings then application and clear the RAM.
When the sufficient amount of memory is clear from your mobile then again install whatsapp.